# Выгрузка из Java в Word

Tags: java, ms-word

У меня есть приложение на Java + Hibernate. Мне надо формировать отчёты в ворде. Есть шаблон. Там грубо говоря 1 строка и таблица. Я долго мучался с Apache POI и ничего не получилось. Подскажите как мне реализовать выгрузку.

[image: Шаблоны такого типа]

```
String templateName = "D:/aktProvStInd.doc";
            String outputName = "D:/aktProvStIndResult.doc";
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(templateName));
            Range range = doc.getRange();
            range.replaceText("<spPuName>", jurnalResult.get(0).getSpMeId().getSpSlId().getSpPuId().getNaim());
            for(int i=0; i < jurnalResult.size(); i++){
                datePovStr = formatter.format(jurnalResult.get(i).getDatePov());
                range.replaceText("<num>", Integer.toString(i+1));
                range.replaceText("<date>", datePovStr);
                range.replaceText("<spMe>", jurnalResult.get(i).getSpMeId().getNaim());
                range.replaceText("<spSi>", jurnalResult.get(i).getSpSiId().getMarka());
                range.replaceText("<invNom>", jurnalResult.get(i).getInvNom());
                range.replaceText("<result>", "годен");
            }   
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputName);
            doc.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

Comment: А что не так с Apache POI? На данный момент это самая стабильная библиотека для работы с оффисовскими документами

Comment: Ну бросьте пример кода для выгрузки в этот шаблон) Если XWPFDocument создаём(docx) то не понятно как вставить в шаблон поле и таблицу получается только создать в конце документа. Если HWPFDocument то строки вставляются отлично, range.replaceText("<spPuName>", jurnalResult.get(0).getSpMeId().getSpSlId().getSpPuId().getNaim());. А вот как коллекцию залить в существующую таблицу не понятно.

Comment: Бросьте пример кода, который у вас не работает и тогда будем разбираться конкретно по вашему вопросу

Comment: @РоманДанилов Я код добавил. Он там выгрузка в таблицу и написана не правильно. Мне надо добавлять и создавать строки в таблице. Я не знаю как. В интернете не нашёл примеров. Только если создать новую таблицу в конце документа

Comment: @NightWolf возможно перед добавлением строк вам надо прочитать содержимое файла, дополнить его, а потом все записать в файл.

Comment: @РоманДанилов и как это сделать? Чтобы осталась разметка, определило таблицу и в неё записало?